# Why doesn't ungroup() work when counting number of different columns containing a value by variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have in my dataset a variable called APP_ID which values can be repeated, and several columns which names start by “NICE_”. I’m trying to count, by APP_ID, the number of **different** “NICE_” columns that contains a value different than zero. For instance, for the following APP_ID the value should be 7 because there are ones in 7 different columns.:

| APP_ID | NICE_1 | NICE_2 | NICE_3 | NICE_4 | NICE_5 | NICE_6 | NICE_7 | NICE_8 | NICE_9 | NICE_10 | NICE_11 | NICE_12 | NICE_13 | NICE_14 | NICE_15 | NICE_16 | NICE_17 | NICE_18 | NICE_19 | NICE_20 | NICE_21 | NICE_22 | NICE_23 | NICE_24 | NICE_25 | NICE_26 | NICE_27 | NICE_28 | NICE_29 | NICE_30 | NICE_31 | NICE_32 | NICE_33 | NICE_34 | NICE_35 | NICE_36 | NICE_37 | NICE_38 | NICE_39 | NICE_40 | NICE_41 | NICE_42 | NICE_43 | NICE_44 | NICE_45 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The point is that I managed to do so, by using:

```
data_QI %>%
  arrange(APP_ID) %>% # Just to have them in order
  select(APP_ID, starts_with("NICE_")) %>% # Select only the variables I’ll work with
  group_by(APP_ID) %>%
  summarize_all(list(sum)) %>%
  mutate(APPNICENUM = rowSums(. != 0) - 1 ) # -1 to not count the column APP_ID.
```

The problem comes when I try to ungroup the observations. I mean, I need the repeated APP_ID to have the same APPNICENUM. However, adding ungroup() to the pipe doesn’t seem to work.

I wonder if there is a way to ungroup the data frame once all those operations are done. Or maybe there is a different (and simplier?) approach to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to keep the same number of rows as your original data but just add a new column which has count of columns that have 1 in it for each `APP_ID` ?

Try this answer -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- data_QI %>%
  group_by(APP_ID) %>%
  mutate(res = sum(colSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with('NICE'))) > 0)) %>%
  ungroup

result
```

Comment: Regarding your question, yes, that was precisely what I wanted to do.
And the code worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`summarise_all` will automatically remove the grouping, so there is no need for `ungroup` afterwards:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~APP_ID, ~NICE_1, ~NICE_2,
  38, 0, 0,
  38, 0, 0,
  38, 1, 1
)
data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   APP_ID NICE_1 NICE_2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     38      0      0
#> 2     38      0      0
#> 3     38      1      1

result <-
  data %>%
  group_by(APP_ID) %>%
  summarize_all(list(sum)) %>%
  # -1 to not count APP_ID
  mutate(APPNICENUM = rowSums(. != 0) - 1)
result
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   APP_ID NICE_1 NICE_2 APPNICENUM
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     38      1      1          2

result %>% groups()
#> list()
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
data_QI %>%
    group_by(APP_ID) %>% 
    summarise(res = sum(across(everything(), sum)), .groups = 'drop')
```